# Why does this service stop?

Tags: android

I have the following Service that is meant to check a web API.

The Implementation is meant to retry the HTTP request 5 times before issuing a notification.

Anyway it seems that the service simply stops after the first attempt.

Please what is going on???

```
public class CreditcheckService extends IntentService {
    public CreditcheckService() {
    super("CreditcheckService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String phone = "";
    phone = intent.getStringExtra("phone");
    checkcreditonline(phone);
    Log.e("inizio il service","inizio il service");

}

private void checkcreditonline(final String phone) {
    final Handler h = new Handler();

    final JsonHttpResponseHandler jsonHttpResponseHandler = new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        private int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject arg0) {
            int cazzo=0;
            cazzo++;
            try {
                String status = arg0.getString("credit");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                String status = arg0.getString("error");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
             //IF FAILED SHOULD RETRY, BUT IT DOESN'T
            if (counter < 5) {
                                    //HERE THE SUCCESSIVE ATTEMPTS
                h.postDelayed(new WebserviceRunnable(this, phone), 5000);
            } else {

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(CreditcheckService.this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.unable_to))
                        .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.please_connect));
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0));
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(999, mBuilder.build());
            }
            counter++;
        }
    };

    h.post(new WebserviceRunnable(jsonHttpResponseHandler, phone));
}

private class WebserviceRunnable implements Runnable {
    private JsonHttpResponseHandler jsonHttpResponseHandler;
    private String email;

    public WebserviceRunnable(
            JsonHttpResponseHandler jsonHttpResponseHandler, String aEmail) {
        this.jsonHttpResponseHandler = jsonHttpResponseHandler;
        this.email = aEmail;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            WebServiceApi.get(
                    "rest/credit/get/" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "utf-8"),
                    null, jsonHttpResponseHandler);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can u please check your logcat for any exception or so??
Please post your logcat too

Comment: @Atish Agrawal thanks Atish nothing in Logcat :-(((

Comment: log the throwable right in the beginning of `public void onFailure(Throwable arg0)`, just to check if it arrives

Comment: try debugging your code..place breakpoints at several lines and check

Comment: i like your variable naming conventions

Comment: @Dtex   hehehe :-)))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onHandleIntent in IntentService is asynchronous.

When onHandleIntent exits, the Service is stopped.

So don't post a message to a Handler, instead do it directly in checkcreditonline().

Comment: thanks Doctoror Drive, I am not sure I understand, I do not use any Handler, any asynchronous work that i do is in  `checkcreditonline(final String phone `

Comment: IntentService calls every onHandleIntent in new thread. When all onHandleIntent exited, the service is stopped.  When you call handler.post in checkcreditonline, the checkcreditonline method exits and then onHandleIntent exits, while Handler's Runnable starts doing the job. Remove the Handler and put WebserviceRunnable's void run() code in checkcreditonline to make Service wait for completion.